# Front wheel making a tick noise with each rotation ans the wheel does not run freely when spun by hand, stops soon after the click noise

Tags: road-bike, disc-brake, freewheel, front, clicking

I just bought a new Triban 500 from Decathlon.  During the first ride I noticed a click sound with each rotation of the wheel (sounds like a car indicator being on).  When I spin the wheel by hand it makes the click sound then comes to a halt soon after the click.

The bike has mechanical disc brakes.

Comment: Usually when you have this sort of intermittent noise from a wheel the problem is that the brakes are rubbing.

Comment: Do you have a cyclecomputer or speedometer fitted?

Comment: Could you post a video of your wheel spinning?

Comment: @DanielRHicks Disc brakes in my experience tend to be more of a swoosh or squeal than clicking.  For clicking I would guess bearings in the hub more likely.  Can confirm if noise continues after removing the caliper and spinning by hand again.   Would also suggest being new, should be more than feasible to check with Decathlon for advise